# Simple Matrix order question... I think!

Tags: matrix, ce-image, image-galleries, orderby

I'm sure this is an easy one to answer.

I have a matrix field which I am using together with CE Image to create a gallery. It contains two columns and a variable number of rows depending on how many images it contains.

Like so:

[image: matrix]

```
{gallery limit="1"}

    {exp:ce_img:pair src="{image_url}" crop="yes|smart_scale" width="420" height="315" allow_scale_larger="yes" filter="sharpen" limit="1" quality='60' add_dims="no"}

    <img src="{made}" alt="{title}"/>

        {/exp:ce_img:pair}

{/_gallery}
```

But I want the image to be the one that is "1" in the Image Order Number (image_order) column.

Comment: You know that Matrix rows are drag and drop to reorder, right? So unless you need a secondary sort order you could just reorder the rows in the Publish form and rely on the actual order of the Matrix field instead of creating an "order" column.

Comment: yep, that would fine, had it not been for the fact that there are over 2000 entries! Wouldn't want to do that manually! :)

Comment: I see. Part of your import project. Good call!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that was simple! just added the `orderby="image_order"` parameter to the matrix tag pair.

I had tried that originally, but it was using the already cached images. Once they were deleted out, it regenerated the right ones.

:)